# error precompiling assets when moving to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to move my project to production,
trying to

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

gives me an error, without specifying in which file it is.

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
(sass):89
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1207:in `expected'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1137:in `expected'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:406:in `_to_tree'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
```

how do I findout in which file that error occurs?
even with --trace it doesnt tell me.

Comment: While ago, I had the same problem with a js syntax. The same problem, in the compression process. My solution was to create a script to compress each file and check which one was causing the error.

Comment: but is says its an invalid CSS, how come its a js?

Comment: I was saying my case. Same situation, but with a js file syntax error. The solution I found was to compress each file individually to find out which one was invalid.

Comment: You could also try https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface, if you don't mind setting up npm packages. I use it frequently, works well.

Comment: Is there any compiling error when running your project in development mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found this issue while researching: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/368. Apparently, you'll have to check each file to find out which one is failing to compile.

But you can create a rake task to help with the process:

Just add the following code to a `lib/tasks/assets.rake` file

```
namespace :assets do

  desc "Find Sass::SyntaxError files..."
  task find_scss_with_error: :environment do
    files = Dir.glob( Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "**/*")).grep(/.*\.[css|scss]/)
    files.each do |file|
        print "Trying to compile #{file}..."
        template = File.read(file)
        sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new(template)
        begin
            sass_engine.render
            print "[OK]"
        rescue
            print "[ERROR]"
        end
        puts
    end
  end

end
```

and run

```
rake assets:find_scss_with_error
```

Results:

```
Trying to compile /data/ruby/scss-comments-failure/app/assets/stylesheets/example.css...[ERROR]
Trying to compile /data/ruby/scss-comments-failure/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css...[OK]
```

Some notes:

- It'll check for `*.css` and `*.scss` files, including subdirectories.
- The script will not output compression to file. It's just a in-memory test.